# Print a random string generated

Tags: python, django, string, random, django-views

I have this code on my views.py

```
import string, random

def draegg_view(size=40, chars=string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
```

My question is how could I print the random string generated since this code?, I can execute this code on python console but i wanna see the result on a page!!

Thanks.

Comment: Why not try and print it to the console? `print(draegg_view())`

Comment: Thank you for answering, I already tried to print this on console but i wanna see the result on my browser like this for example: http://www.miniwebtool.com/django-secret-key-generator/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is a *django view* you are talking about, you need to return an [`HttpResponse` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects).

In the simplest case, it would be:

```
import random
import string

from django.http import HttpResponse


def draegg_view(request):
    size = 40
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    result = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

Note that a view is one of the key components/concepts in Django, make sure you study [Writing Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#writing-views) documentation section and the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) carefully.

Comment: +1 since you gave him a django example ... my answer just gives him an easy way to just render this only ... I assumed from his question he had little to no understanding of django (and I didnt want to have to go into routing and all that ...)

Comment: @JoranBeasley thank you for getting me a little closer to the gold django badge :), there is definitely more to cover here: routing, forms (in case the OP wants to have `size` and `chars` coming from a form) etc. +1 to your option too.

Answer (score 4):

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask()
@app.route("/")
def dreaegg_view(size=40...):
    return ...

app.run()
```

is probably the easiest way to get it displayed in an html page ...